# inserting data from parent table to child table in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I want to insert a data from parent table to child table if it isn't already in the child table.

```
create table parents(
 c1 varchar  (100) primary key,
  c2 varchar  (100),

);
CREATE TABLE child
(
   c1 varchar (100) PRIMARY KEY, 
    c3 varchar (100),

     FOREIGN KEY (c1) REFERENCES parents(c1)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, by data, you mean column c1 only, you can insert into child using a select from parent where you can filter the row to those which aren't present in the child table.

```
insert into child (c1, c3)
select c1, c2
from parents
where c1 not in (
    select c1 from child
    );
```