# How to add or insert foreign key value in child table from parent table using insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use the primary key of parent table in my child tables. I have created a foreign key to connect QUESTION and ANSWER table with each other.
below is code of my database:

user table

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, -- unique index
  username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  password VARBINARY(255) NOT NULL,                -- password hash, binary
  firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  address VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  phone BIGINT DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE question (
   question_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  -- unique index
   questions TEXT NOT NULL,    
   question_text TEXT NOT NULL,        
   user_id INT NOT NULL,                                 -- id of the user who have asked
   CONSTRAINT user_to_question FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

 CREATE TABLE answer (
  answer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  -- unique index
  answer_text TEXT NOT NULL,
  question_id INT NOT NULL,                           -- what question it answers on
  user_id INT NOT NULL,                               -- id of the user who have answered
  CONSTRAINT user_to_answer FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (user_id),
  CONSTRAINT question_to_answer FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES question (question_id)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

So, In USER table I have added a new value:

```
  insert into user values(1,"krish","123456789","Krish","D","krish@gmail.com","Mumbai MH","98776");
```

Now in QUESTION table I want to add a new value and I want to use the user_id value from USER table. Since user_id is foreign key in QUESTION table. So, far i have tried this query but its not working.

```
 insert into question (question_id,questions,question_text)
 SELECT user_id
 FROM user
 where user_id = 1;
 values (1,"What is java","Please Explain in details");
```

I have referred this question and solution but its not working. [inserting data from parent table to child table in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47298851/inserting-data-from-parent-table-to-child-table-in-postgres)

Comment: If you know that `user_id = 1`, you can just put `1` in the `VALUES` list, you don't need `SELECT`.

Comment: hey @Barmar In my case user_id is Auto increment primary key. So let say In USER table there is user with user_id = 1 who asked a question which will generate a question_id, so I should be able to retrieve that user_id from USER table and insert in the QUESTION table. It is not necessary that both user_id and question_id will be same. user with user_id 2 can ask a question which may or may not have the question_id = 2.

Comment: It would make more sense if you were looking up the user ID by username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are trying is something like:

```
insert into question ( question_id,
                       questions,
                       question_text
                     )
SELECT user_id as question_id,
       "What is java" as questions,
       "Please Explain in details" as question_text
FROM user
where user_id = 1 ;
```

But as far as I can see you cant insert only this values because on

```
CREATE TABLE answer (
  answer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  answer_text TEXT NOT NULL,
  question_id INT NOT NULL,                           
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
```

you have `user_id INT NOT NULL` so it expects a value.

Something like :

```
insert into question ( question_id,
                       questions,
                       question_text,
                       user_id
                      )
SELECT user_id as question_id,
       "What is java" as questions,
       "Please Explain in details" as question_text,
       user_id
FROM user
where user_id = 1 ;
```

Comment: hi @ergest-basha In my case user_id is Auto increment primary key. So let say In USER table there is user with user_id = 1 who asked a question which will generate a question_id, so I should be able to retrieve that user_id from USER table and insert in the QUESTION table. It is not necessary that both user_id and question_id will be same. user with user_id 2 can ask a question which may or may not have the question_id = 2.

Comment: I hope this adds more clarity to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `user_id` that you're selecting from the `user` table, there's no need for the `SELECT` at all, just put it in the `VALUES` list.

```
INSERT INTO question (question_id,questions,question_text, user_id)
VALUES (1,"What is java","Please Explain in details", 1);
```

You would use a `SELECT` if you need to look up the `user_id` using other columns. In that case, you add the fixed values to the `SELECT` list.

```
INSERT INTO question (question_id,questions,question_text, user_id)
SELECT 1,"What is java","Please Explain in details", user_id
FROM users
WHERE username = 'krish';
```

If you're doing this immediately after creating the user, you can also use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to get the `user_id` that was assigned using auto-increment.

```
INSERT INTO question (question_id,questions,question_text, user_id)
VALUES (1,"What is java","Please Explain in details", LAST_INSERT_ID());
```